# Brightness adjustment not shown in Windows Mobility Center on HP Pavillion laptop

Tags: windows-7, laptop, display, brightness, hp-pavilion

The Windows Mobility Center (displayed when you press <kbd>[image: Winkey]</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>) normally shows a slider control for adjusting the brightness of the display on laptops. On my older Dell laptop this worked fine, but on my new HP Pavillion dm4t, the slider is absent. There is also no adjustment in the Power Settings in the Control Panel, like there usually is.

Windows has *some* ability to adjust the brightness, because the display automatically dims after a configurable amount of time. I can adjust the brightness using the hotkeys on the keyboard, which are controlled by an HP driver I have installed, but I would still like to be able to adjust this from within Windows.

Does anybody know how to get this working? Is there another driver package I need to install? Is there some registry setting I can set up in Windows to get it to work? Does anybody else have a recent HP laptop who can confirm if they have this problem as well? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently reinstalled Windows, and did not install HP's keyboard quick launch driver. The brightness controls now appear normally in Windows, by themselves. I don't know if uninstalling the driver would have fixed it with the original install, but at this point I'm considering the problem solved.

Answer (score -1):

I have this feature on my Windows 7, which is Professional. Apparently, the Mobility Center is only available on Professional, Ultimate and Enterprise. It's not on Home Premium or Starter.

Comment: I have Windows 7 Professional, so I don't think this is the problem. Windows Mobility Center does appear, it's just missing the tile for brightness.

Comment: I'm running Windows 7 Home Premium on an HP laptop, and I'm not experiencing this problem.  The Windows Mobility Center is present on my system.